# Javamelody reports in Sonar

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, sonarqube, java-melody

Am using javamelody to monitor the server's runtime performance. I also use sonar with jenkins to output jacoco reports. 
Javamelody supports PDF report download. is there any way i can see that report with other sonar reports or maybe download this pdf to a disk location and show it up from there in the sonar page?

Comment: Interesting idea, but it doesn't make logical sense to me.  SonarQube reports metrics by project, you're trying to include monitoring of the server in the same data if I understand the question. They're different kinds of data.  Would having JavaMelody automatically email you a report automatically be better?

Comment: the thing is that we use javamelody to run performance test profiles everyday and download a report. to show all these download reports in a consolidated manner instead of emailing them, i was trying to include these files in sonarqube somehow. like maybe a new link in sonar dashboard, which you click, shows you all the PDFs downloaded using javamelody.
it would be helpful if there is any way to show custom files in sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a project information link to the JavaMelody page, which would let you generate and save a report.  You'll need to log in with admin permission, then (in SonarQube 4.0) navigate to a project, Configuration, Project Links.  Add a JavaMelody label, and the URL to the report you want to come up by default.  The link will now appear on the project's dashboard, in the Description widget.

I haven't tried it, but it might be possible to use a file:// URL to link to a file in a known location accessible to your browser.  That might work for you if you can get the JavaMelody reports on a shared filesystem.

Comment: thanks, let me try that. i hope it works. will post back with what happens.

Comment: not able to link to local files on the machine, though can add links to web resources. i am thinking of setting up an ftp server and maybe adding a link in sonarQube to show report PDF files by re-directing to ftp server.